# Nested Crystal if statement not working

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports, formula

Morning Guys,

I have the following formula in a Crystal Sub-report and it isn't returning any values. I know data exists for over a dozen records, I've used the check function and no syntax errors are given and I've followed the example as given in the following question '[Crystal Report: How to evaluate multiple IF statements in one formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220519/crystal-report-how-to-evaluate-multiple-if-statements-in-one-formula)'.

The formula is as follows;

```
(if {?Pm-Enquiry.EnquiryId} <1000 and
{DocumentType.DocumentSubtype} = "DocumentSubtype1" then
left ({DocumentSubtype1Table.Field1},3) else
left ({DocumentSubtype1Table.Field1},4)
);
(if {?Pm-Enquiry.EnquiryId} <1000 and
{DocumentType.DocumentSubtype} = "DocumentSubtype2" then
left ({DocumentSubtype2Table.Field1},3) else
left ({DocumentSubtype2Table.Field1},4)
);
(if {?Pm-Enquiry.EnquiryId} <1000 and
{DocumentType.DocumentSubtype} = "DocumentSubtype1" then
left ({DocumentSubtype3Table.Field1},3) else
left ({DocumentSubtype3Table.Field1},4)
);
```

The formula should determine if the ID is less than or greater than three digits and retrieve the first 3/4 digits from the DocumentSubtypeTable. Unfortunately the ID has been amalgamated with the date in this field making this formula necessary.

Any help you guys could give would be really appreciated.

Comment: is that your created formula? what do you want to do?

Comment: This is my amended formula. Basically there is a field in each of these document subtypes an example of which would be '1992 12/01/2016' or '123 01/01/2017'.
I only want the formula to return the first 4 or 3 digits of that field based on the length of the Enquiry ID which is those digits.

Comment: Show a given example and a given result.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps since you are not returning a value.
Try the following (define a variable, fill your result in it, then return it.):

```
StringVar StrValue;

(if {?Pm-Enquiry.EnquiryId} <1000 and {DocumentType.DocumentSubtype} = "DocumentSubtype1" then
StrValue := left ({DocumentSubtype1Table.Field1},3) else
StrValue := left ({DocumentSubtype1Table.Field1},4)
);

(if {?Pm-Enquiry.EnquiryId} <1000 and {DocumentType.DocumentSubtype} = "DocumentSubtype2" then
StrValue := left ({DocumentSubtype2Table.Field1},3) else
StrValue := left ({DocumentSubtype2Table.Field1},4)
);

(if {?Pm-Enquiry.EnquiryId} <1000 and {DocumentType.DocumentSubtype} = "DocumentSubtype1" then
StrValue := left ({DocumentSubtype3Table.Field1},3) else
StrValue := left ({DocumentSubtype3Table.Field1},4)
);

StrValue;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I haven't used Crystal a great deal what would example values be for the variable?

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify your question? I didn't understand it

Comment: In this example the `StrValue` is the variable we are defining, and filling, then returning.